# ERROR -- : Response was: 307 -- Temporary Redirect when trying to upload to bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I get 307 when uploading to a bucket with Amazon's Ruby gem (2.10.2). Another bucket works fine (both were created today). I checked the name and I didn't misspell it. What is causing the error?

Comment: If you created, deleted, then recreated the bucket, that could cause this behavior for a short period of time, and if anyone ever had the bucket before you it might cause a similar issue... but should have worked itself out fairly quickly.  Are you still experiencing this?  Are the 2 buckets in the same S3 region?  Did you capture any additional headers and/or response body on the error?

Comment: It solved itself. I guess it was a temporary error as you said!

Answer (score 3):

307 is the HTTP code for "Temporary Redirect". Per the [S3 docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Redirects.html) on such redirects:

> #### Temporary Request Redirection
>
> A temporary redirect is a type of error response that signals to the requester that he should resend his request to a different endpoint.
>
> Due to the distributed nature of Amazon S3, requests can be temporarily routed to the wrong facility. This is most likely to occur immediately after buckets are created or deleted. For example, if you create a new bucket and immediately make a request to the bucket, you might receive a temporary redirect, depending on the location constraint of the bucket. If you created the bucket in the US East (N. Virginia) region (s3.amazonaws.com endpoint) you will not see the redirect because this is also the default endpoint. However, if bucket is created in any other region, any requests for the bucket will go to the default endpoint while the bucket's DNS entry is propagated. The default endpoint will redirect the request to the correct endpoint with a HTTP 302 *(sic)* response.

The claim that 302s are used for these redirects seems to be an error in the docs, since it contradicts both the behaviour you have witnessed, the behaviour I have witnessed, and the "Example REST API Redirect" later in the same page of the docs.

So your options are:

- If you face no urgency, just wait; it will fix itself within a few minutes or hours.
- If you need these redirects to never occur, create all your buckets in the US East region.
- If neither of the above is an option, ensure that whatever HTTP clients you are using to access the buckets are capable of following the `Location:` header in the redirect and configured to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Waiting didn't help in my case - I had to invalidate everything with path "/*" in the AWS cloudfront console to fix the 307 with subsequent "Access denied" on the forward to the private S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the newly created S3 is not ready, wait mins, hours or even one day.

---

Official Answer by AWS

[**AWS Knowledge Center: Why am I getting an HTTP 307 Temporary Redirect response from Amazon S3?**](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-http-307-response/)

Last updated: 2021-04-05

When I send requests to an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket, Amazon S3 returns a 307 Temporary Redirect response. Why am I receiving this error?

**Resolution**

After you create an Amazon S3 bucket, up to 24 hours can pass before the bucket name propagates across all AWS Regions. During this time, you might receive the 307 Temporary Redirect response for requests to Regional endpoints that aren't in the same Region as your bucket. For more information, see Temporary request redirection.

To avoid the 307 Temporary Redirect response, send requests only to the Regional endpoint in the same Region as your S3 bucket:

If you're using the AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI) to access the bucket, configure the AWS CLI. Your AWS CLI must reside in the same Region as your Amazon S3 bucket.

Note: If you receive errors when running AWS CLI commands, make sure that you’re using the most recent AWS CLI version.

If you're using an Amazon CloudFront distribution with an Amazon S3 origin, CloudFront forwards requests to the default S3 endpoint ( s3.amazonaws.com). The default S3 endpoint is in the us-east-1 Region. If you must access Amazon S3 within the first 24 hours of creating the bucket, you can change the origin domain name of the distribution. The domain name must include the Regional endpoint of the bucket. For example, if the bucket is in us-west-2, you can change the origin domain name from awsexamplebucketname.s3.amazonaws.com to awsexamplebucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com.

Tip: To reduce the number of DNS redirects and DNS propagation issues, specify the AWS Region of your bucket in all HTTP requests. For example, if you're using the AWS CLI, include the --region parameter in your request to specify the AWS Region.

### Related Stack Overflow Question

[AWS CloudFront returns http 307 when origin is S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38706424/aws-cloudfront-returns-http-307-when-origin-is-s3-bucket)